# How do I redirect from my react website to another website without getting a 503 error?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, service

I'm trying to redirect to a website, say xyz.com, using a breadcrumb in my react app from localhost. The redirect from xyz.com to localhost works fine. I've added the link to xyz.com in an 'href' in my breadcrumb. When I click on it, I get a message saying "This request was blocked during CSRF Filtering!" and a 503 error. Also, xyz.com has a etcd service registry that I can use but I don't know how to. I'm new to server-side functionality and don't have much idea about passing headers, etc. How do I solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried googling that error message?

Comment: Yes, I did. I even tried a few things here and there but that didn't work either.